# rename function in dplyr does not work

Tags: r, data-cleaning

As the title of this post suggests, I am trying to rename some of the columns in my dataframe, but the code does not seem to work for me. There is no error message. So, I am wondering whether I am doing something wrong or missed something. This is the MWE.

```
install.packages("rsdmx")
install.packages("dplyr")
library(rsdmx)
library(dplyr)
#Download data 
Assets.PIT <- readSDMX("http://widukind-api.cepremap.org/api/v1/sdmx/IMF/data/IFS/..Q.BFPA-BP6-USD")
Assets.PIT <- as.data.frame(Assets.PIT) 

names(Assets.PIT)[10]<-"A.PI.T"

# Keep the required columns 
A.port.inv.total<-Assets.PIT[c("WIDUKIND_NAME","REF-AREA","TIME_PERIOD","A.PI.T")]
```

So in the above code I want to rename some of the column in `A.port.inv.total`, So, I am using:

```
# Rename columns
rename(A.port.inv.total, Country=WIDUKIND_NAME, year=TIME_PERIOD)
```

but the resulting output is again:

```
names(A.port.inv.total)
[1] "WIDUKIND_NAME" "REF-AREA"      "TIME_PERIOD"   "A.PI.T"
```

**Updated Clarification**
I want to rename the column vector `WIDUKIND_NAME` and `TIME_PERIOD` to `Country` and `year`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine to me, but I think you have to assign the result of the `rename` function:

```
rename(A.port.inv.total, Country=WIDUKIND_NAME, year=TIME_PERIOD)
> names(A.port.inv.total)
[1] "WIDUKIND_NAME" "REF-AREA"      "TIME_PERIOD"   "A.PI.T"  

A.port.inv.total <- rename(A.port.inv.total, Country=WIDUKIND_NAME, year=TIME_PERIOD)
> names(A.port.inv.total)
[1] "Country"  "REF-AREA" "year"     "A.PI.T"
```

Comment: That's true, it works now for me, too. However, it should have worked without the assignment, no ? It's a serious deficiency in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, I don't know why it doesn't work that way. I was confused with the other `rename` functions of other packages too.

Comment: It's not just rename. All objects in R are immutable (at least the basic ones you will encounter). You can only change them by making an altered copy and reassigning the copy to the same name.